# Error SQL statement in PutSQL processor not routing to failure relationship

Tags: apache-nifi

I've got an error in the PutSql processor because there is a syntax error in the insert query, but the flowfile did not route to the failed relationship, instead the session is rolled back and stuck to the incoming queue

can someone explain me why this is happen?

or can I force the flowfile that have an error routed to failure relationship
or is there a way to remove specific flowfile that caused error in queue, so the other flowfile can be processed

[image: screenshoot]

Thanks,

Comment: Is the `Rollback on Failure` set to false?

Comment: I have tried to set the value to true or false, but it still does not routed to any relationship and stuck in queue